Adjusting underfloor heating thermistor resistance to match a different controller
I have DeviMat underfloor heating installed in my bathroom, presently matched to a Danfoss DeviReg "smart" thermostat. There's a matching Devi heating probe installed under the floor which I can't replace.
I want to replace it for one that supports IFTTT but it seems that most of the controllers are graded 10Kohm at 25c whereas the DeviReg expects 15Kohm at 25c.
I realise the curve probably won't match, but it's not a terribly accurate system in any case. I tend to just whack it up to max when the electricity is in cheap rates to take the chill out of the floor for the day.
I would like to get the probe as accurate as possible though, so I was thinking I could put a 30kOhm resistor in parallel with the temperature sensor to bring it more into line with what it expects.
Would this work? anything I should be beware of? I haven't checked the voltage it sends to the thermistor yet, and I'm hoping it's not 220v otherwise I suspect it would need to dissipate a lot of heat itself.
Any advice?

Any controller with enough electronics for a network connection (for IFTTT to use) can be programmed for a different thermistor response curve.  Whether that's user-configurable is a different story, but you may be able to find that out from user forums before you select your new purchase.

Also: mostly duplicate of https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/527425/1743
